# iOS display notification based on incoming phone call

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, telephony

Is it possible to have a background app display a notification based on who is contact details from an incoming caller, either before the call is answered or during?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the system will not allow you to interact with phone calls in any way.

Comment: Yep, the closest you can get is the Core Telephony framework, but still it won't help with what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image for certain people in the address book using the Address Book API. That way, a certain background image (potentially with a textual message) will be shown, based on who is calling.

Answer (score 0):

With time, things change. Look at sync.me, when you get an incoming call, the latest post on facebook will show just above the accept/decline button. Though I still can't get the idea of how it is done.